# iFrame Loading Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension that modifies the chrome://extension frame page. In order to do so, I must first load the elements inside an iframe so that I'd be able to modify it. When I try using this code on the chrome console, it returns me the correct iframe that I want to load:

```
document.getElementsByName("extensions");
```

However, when I try using this code, it fails with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined":

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByName("extensions");
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
When using:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByName("extensions")[0];
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

It returns this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "chrome://chrome" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at <anonymous>:2:22
```

Comment: To be a bit pedantic: [.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). In this case, the solution, add `[0]`, is the same. NodeLists are static, where HTMLCollections are live. NodeLists are also in the process of gaining some convenient Array-like methods, which are not available for HTMLCollection.

Comment: thanks for your help @wOxxOm. the error that shows up now is "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "chrome://chrome" from accessing a cross-origin frame." I've tried searching for an answer myself already, any fix for this? Sorry, I'm a beginner in this

Comment: @Omega, Given that you have no Answers, yet, feel free to [edit] the question to be different (i.e. about what happens when you have the `[0]`). For Answering, it helps to see the actual code you are asking about, not just have it sort-of referred to in comments. Once you have an Answer, the question should be edited to improve it, but should not be changed to be a different question such as to invalidate an answer. As wOxxOm stated, we are going to need more information to actually answer the new question. We are going to need a [mcve] that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm The iFrame is the same one that shows the extension page on chrome://extensions, so if I understand you correct; the iFrame is defined as "<iframe name="extensions" role="presentation" src="chrome://extensions-frame/" data-ready="true"></iframe>" and it's loaded when I inspect element on any extension

Comment: Inject your content scripts in all frames using the corresponding parameter, see the docs.